# Почему внутри функции .map() нельзя писать фигурные скобки для стрелочной функции. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Столкнулся с такой особенностью, которая меня, как новичка, немного смущает.

```
   {people.map((element) => 
     <li>{element.name}</li>
   )}
```

Есть такой код, он работает ( выводит список элементов на страницу )

Но когда пишу так, работать перестает ( не выводит ), при этом нигде никаких ошибок.

```
{people.map((element) => {
    <li>{element.name}</li>
  }
)}
```

Ведь по сути эти записи эквивалентны, можно по идее даже записать так, но так тоже не работает.

```
{people.map(function (element) {
    <li>{element.name}</li>
  }
)}
```

Что я упустил? Получается функция `map` работает только с современной формой объявления функции ( стрелочной) и при этом строго без фигурных скобок?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: "эти записи эквивалентны" -- нет.

Comment: в стрелочной функции есть два варианта написания с фигурными скобками и без. ....сейчас не будем реакт вообще приплетать. знаете разницу?)

Comment: вы return забыли просто

Comment: нет о разнице между объявлением стрелочной функции с фигурными стрелками и без не знаю, расскажите. пожалуйста.

Comment: просто читаю mdn написано так

Comment: (param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements }
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
эквивалентно

Comment: вы просто не прочитали до конца документацию https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions  *"Если единственным оператором в выражении стрелочной функции является return,  можно удалить return и окружающие фигурные скобки"*

Comment: ааа, спасибо большое!!!!!))) такую тонкость сложно где-то прочесть, очень помогли!)))

Answer (score 1):

Когда стрелочная функция объявляется без скобок - return прописывается автоматически, при объявлении стрелочной функции в скобках, его нужно прописывать вручную.