# Что делает метод .json()

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, rest

Пишу такой запрос

```
   fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=javascript&maxResults=40")
    .then(response => response.json()
    )
    .then (data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
```

Если не сделать response.json() - приходит пустой массив. Исходя из этого у меня возник вопрос - что именно делает метод .json()? Превращает json формат в объект? но для этого же есть JSON.parse() и он мне не помог, когда я поставил его вместо .json.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Привет, https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch тут подробно описано

Comment: и еще, что означает => это сокращенная запись функции что ли, но ведь нету круглых скобок даже. Или это уникальный синтаксис для промисов?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, там написано только response.json() – декодирует ответ в формате JSON, мне это ни о чем не говорит.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/arrow-functions-basics про стрелочные функции

Comment: learn.javascript.ru/arrow-functions-basics Там есть some = () => {} но про some => some ничего не сказано

Comment: если один аргумент то скобки можно опустить и если сразу возвращается значение можно не ставить фигурные скобки и писать return

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128929/discussion-between-lev-shportak-and--web).

Comment: Есть подозрение, что автор — тролль, потому что тут он сам отвечает на вопрос, который задаёт в здесь в комментариях: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1319036/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-map-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8/1319296#1319296

Comment: Это другое! :D делать мне нечего сидеть тут кого-то тролить, просто я забыл, ну точнее там оно немного понятнее выглядело чем тут потому мне в глаза и бросилось, а теперь уже окончательно закрепил

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря помощи Lev Shportak я узнал, что
.json() указывает объекту класса response формат, в котором мы хотим получить данные.

Comment: Response.json() принимает поток Response и считывает его до конца. Он возвращает promise, который разрешается в результат разбора тела ответа в качестве стоки JSON. <-- The json() method of the Response interface takes a Response stream and reads it to completion. It returns a promise which resolves with the result of parsing the body text as JSON. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json. То есть, метод возвращает обязательство при благоприятном исходе вернуть объект, который получен после JSON.parse(текст тела ответа).

Comment: @Leonid, но почему в комментарии? Мы бы плюсков накидали за этот хороший ответ))

Comment: @yar85 это вместо минуса за этот ответ)) Я минусы не ставлю.